# Reboot PI flashed via rpiboot without disconnection power

Tags: usb, boot, image, compute-module

I've used `rpiboot` to get access to a raspberrypi's storage and flashed an image.

How can I reboot the raspberry from the terminal.

It should boot into the flashed OS, without any physical action such as disconnecting power?

Comment: Would you please link rpiboot? Also, did you try searching for your question? According to some sources, you can reboot the raspberry pi by typing `reboot` or `sudo reboot`. Also please give more details on **What you are doing** and **What you tried**.

Comment: @Friendlygabe777 - OP is referring to a compute module, rpiboot is how the onboard emmc is flashed

Comment: `flashed an image` - what image? what carrier board are you using? Did you switch from flashing mode to regular mode after you flashed - i.e. enable eMMC boot?

Comment: Ahh. Okay, I understand now.

Comment: I'm flashing either the official or a customized revpi image onto a "Revolution Pi Core S". @JaromandaX

Comment: How can I "switch flashingmodes"? @JaromandaX

Comment: Oh, your Pi is a CM3 - I assumed CM4 - I have no idea about CM3's